# how to get data output length 32 in SHA256 (32 bytes ) in c# or vb.net?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am trying with this c# code but result not getting in 32 bites anybody help me on this

```cs
public static String sha256_hash(string value)

{

    StringBuilder Sb = new StringBuilder(32);

    using (SHA256 hash1 = SHA256Managed.Create())

    {

        Encoding enc = Encoding.UTF32;

        Byte[] result = hash1.ComputeHash(enc.GetBytes(value));

        foreach (byte b in result  )

        Sb.Append(b.ToString("X2").ToLower());

        //foreach (Byte b in result)

        //    Sb.Append(b.ToString("X2").ToLower());

    }

    return Sb.ToString();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following which is adapted from [this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.sha256?view=net-6.0). It takes a string as input and returns a 256-bit (32 byte) hash as a base64 string.

**C#:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace ComputeHashUsingSHA256
{
    public class Helper
    {
        public static string GetHash(string value)
        {
            //ToDo: changed to desired encoding
            return GetHash(value, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        }

        public static string GetHash(string value, System.Text.Encoding encoding)
        {
            string result = string.Empty;

            using (SHA256 mySHA256 = SHA256.Create())
            {
                byte[] valueArr = null;

                if (encoding == System.Text.Encoding.ASCII)
                    valueArr = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value); //convert string value to byte[]
                else if (encoding == System.Text.Encoding.Default)
                    valueArr = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(value); //convert string value to byte[]
                else if (encoding == System.Text.Encoding.UTF7)
                    valueArr = System.Text.Encoding.UTF7.GetBytes(value); //convert string value to byte[]
                else if (encoding == System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
                    valueArr = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value); //convert string value to byte[]
                else if (encoding == System.Text.Encoding.UTF32)
                    valueArr = System.Text.Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(value); //convert string value to byte[]
                else
                    throw new Exception("Encoding not supported");

                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(valueArr))
                {
                    //compute hash
                    byte[] hashValue = mySHA256.ComputeHash(ms);

                    //for testing, output hash value as HEX

                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("hashValue.Length: " + hashValue.Length + " bytes");

                    for (int i = 0; i < hashValue.Length; i++)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write($"{hashValue[i]:X2}");

                        if ((i % 4) == 3)
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(" ");
                    }

                    //convert to Base64 string
                    result = Convert.ToBase64String(hashValue);

                    //convert to string
                    //result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(hashValue);

                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("result: " + result);
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

**VB.NET**

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Security.Cryptography

Module Helper

    Public Function GetHash(value As String)
        Return GetHash(value, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
    End Function

    Public Function GetHash(value As String, specifiedEncoding As System.Text.Encoding) As String
        Dim result As String = String.Empty

        Using mySHA256 As SHA256 = SHA256.Create()
            Dim valueArr As Byte() = Nothing

            Debug.WriteLine("specifiedEncoding.EncodingName: " & specifiedEncoding.EncodingName)

            If specifiedEncoding.EncodingName.Contains("ASCII") Then
                valueArr = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value) 'convert String value To Byte()
            ElseIf specifiedEncoding.EncodingName.Contains("UTF-7") Then
                valueArr = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(value) 'convert String value To Byte()
            ElseIf specifiedEncoding.EncodingName.Contains("UTF-8") Then
                valueArr = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(value) 'convert String value To Byte()
            ElseIf specifiedEncoding.EncodingName.Contains("UTF-32") Then
                valueArr = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(value) 'convert String value To Byte()
            Else
                Throw New Exception("Encoding not supported")
            End If

            Using ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(valueArr)
                Dim hashValue As Byte() = mySHA256.ComputeHash(ms)

                'for testing, output hash value as HEX
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("hashValue.Length: " & hashValue.Length.ToString() & " bytes")

                For i As Integer = 0 To hashValue.Length - 1 Step 1
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write($"{hashValue(i):X2}")

                    If (i Mod 4) = 3 Then
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(" ")
                    End If
                Next

                'convert to Base64 string
                result = Convert.ToBase64String(hashValue)

                'convert to string
                'result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(hashValue)

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("result: " & result)
            End Using
        End Using

        Return result
    End Function
End Module
```

**Resources**:

- [SHA256 Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.sha256?view=net-6.0)
- [Convert.ToBase64String Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string?view=net-6.0)